# What is the difference between an account on the EVM and a contract account?

Tags: contract-development, evm

Based on the description [here](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/accounts/). I can see that a contract account is an Ethereum account that has a codeHash and a storageRoot. However, in the codeHash paragraph differentiate explicitly between Contract accounts & an account on the EVM.

I thought that the contract account is deployed to the EVM whereby other individuals can call it using EOA like MetaMask. However, it seems that I did understand this concept in the right way.

Based on my current understanding there are three accounts in ethereum, one is the EOA, contract account, and account on the EVM.

But, still I am confused between what is the role of an address of a contract account because the codeHash could simply do the role and hence the address of the contract could actually be the codeHash which is sufficient to call the account on the EVM! But, based on some responses I received is the following "it is possible to have the exact same bytecode for two different contract addresses"

I initially had the impression that the, in order to deploy contracts into the EVM, is only through contract account.

Please help me with my puzzeling understanding of how things really work on the EVM. I am really puzzled with all the things I read from different resources online and videos on Youtube!

Comment: actually these docs don't tell you about precompiled accounts, but there are a few addresses that are precompiled to implement certain functions. And they don't exist in the State

Comment: contracts are not deployed to the EVM, they are deployed to the State. You can run EVM in memory with fake accounts if you want, all you have to do is to use another `go-ethereum/core/statedb` package

Comment: " the address of the contract could actually be the codeHash" it can't be because the other types of accounts have no code, and they need to be referenced somehow

Comment: @Nulik I do not think that what you say here is necessarily true! Based on this (link)[https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/evm/] it says that "special state machine; It's the environment in which all Ethereum accounts and smart contracts live." this is in defining EVM! So, EVM is the software that is run on this state machine where the Ethereum account live and they are different to the account on EVM? I am not sure but can you help clarify this? I am non-technical! so please explain it from this kind of perspective.

Comment: @Nulik what do you mean by "fake account" anyone can do any account he/she wishes. Is there something like a "fake" and "authentic" accounts?! This is so unclear to me?

Comment: @Anonymous he was meaning in testing mode.

Comment: @Anonymous the best to understand is to always read the code of the official implementation.